# Is one dimension the same as one space-time?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

In this Cern article, https://home.cern/science/physics/extra-dimensions-gravitons-and-tiny-black-holes, it states:

> "In our everyday lives, we experience three spatial dimensions, and a fourth dimension of time. How could there be more? Einstein’s general theory of relativity tells us that space can expand, contract, and bend. Now if one dimension were to contract to a size smaller than an atom, it would be hidden from our view. But if we could look on a small enough scale, that hidden dimension might become visible again. Imagine a person walking on a tightrope. She can only move backward and forward; but not left and right, nor up and down, so she only sees one dimension. Ants living on a much smaller scale could move around the cable, in what would appear like an extra dimension to the tightrope-walker."

Is this saying that all dimensions are independent?

For example a 2D sheet. One could imagine infinitely squeezing (condensing?) either XY dimension to visually, macro perspective, create a one-dimensional 'line' which is still, nano perspective, a 2D space where an even nano-factor smaller entity could traverse in 2D.

So the question is ... do dimensions actually condense? ... or more accurately 'warp' giving the visual effect of condensing?

For example, lets you have a flat sheet of 2D space-time and you applied a 1D enormous gravity-well to it.

Wouldn't the 'top' of the sheet appear that the 2D sheet has been separated into two while the 'bottom' is where you see the origin of the 1D gravity-well – the two perpendicular 'halves' of spacetime stretching upward to where it forms the 'gap' of the 2D sheet.

Comment: could you provide some picture? It is hard for me to understand what you mean from your description.

Comment: Imagine a 2D sheet with a very long, very heavy, toothpick dropped onto it.